# why is the input type number of <input> field is passing as string?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

am creating a simple component where the user inputs the balance they intends to add and for taking the input from the user this is the template:

```
<h3>Add balance :</h3>
<input #payment type="number">
<button (click)="updateBalance(payment.value)">Update</button>
<span *ngIf="(balance$ | async) as balance" >Your Balance is:{{balance$ | currency}}</span>
```

The current balance is stored in behaviourSubject in "paymentService" and thats injected to component as follows:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { PaymentsService } from '../../services/payments.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payments',
  templateUrl: './payments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payments.component.css'],
  imports:[CommonModule],
  providers:[PaymentsService],
  standalone:true
})
export class PaymentsComponent implements OnInit {
balance$ = this.paymentsService.paymentBalance$;
  constructor( private paymentsService:PaymentsService) { }
  updateBalance(newbalance:HTMLInputElement){
    this.paymentsService.addBalance(newbalance.valueAsNumber);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And finally the paymentService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable(
  {providedIn:'root'}
)
export class PaymentsService {
private paymentSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<number|null>(null);
public paymentBalance$ = this.paymentSubject$.asObservable();

public updateBalance(balance:number){
  const currentBalance = this.paymentSubject$.getValue();
  if(currentBalance){
    const totalBalance = currentBalance - balance;
    this.paymentSubject$.next(totalBalance);
  }
}
public addBalance(balance:number){
  const currentBalance = this.paymentSubject$.getValue();
  if(currentBalance){
    const totalBalance = currentBalance + balance; 
    this.paymentSubject$.next(totalBalance);
  }
}
  constructor() { }

}
```

the value payment value from template is passed to function as html Input Element type in function and then checking for numeric value using value as number in function. But it shows the error =>Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type HTML Input Element.

Is it because of the NAN condition is not handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value property returns `string` value. Use valueAsNumber as below it will return `double` or `NaN`

```
 <button (click)="updateBalance(payment.valueAsNumber)">Update</button>
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-udzbx1?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Comment: Thanks @Chellapan for the answer, apparently the use of currency pipe had been giving error. Apart from that the code works fine.:)